# Strange user in my External drive's Security Properties

Tags: windows-7, security, user

Here is the image showing the odd user in my External drive settings.
Its only inside my external drive. Not my main one.

What does this user represent?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HAeQ8kM.png]

More confusing stuff inside external drive:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the edit Techie007. I hope i get the rights to use images soon ^^ so i don't have to keep using hyperlinks. thanks though!!!

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, without being able to see the entire time, is that its the guid for an unknown user from the system itself or another system all together.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission for an unknown account.  Since it's unknown the permissions dialog shows an ID instead of a name.

Since this is an external drive it was probably applied while the drive was attached to another computer.

In general you're safe to just go ahead and remove unknown account entries like that.

Comment: Ok i see! Thank you for your swift response and explanation on it! Did you see my other question about folder icons not working for my external drive? Does it perhaps have to do with user permissions?

Comment: Oh also. Is this normal when you click delete? http://i.imgur.com/AWIPBmc.png

Comment: Yup it's normal.  It's telling you that the permission on that folder (`F:\XXXXX`) is being inherited from its parent (`F:\ `).  If you want to delete it, you should delete it from `F:\ `.

Comment: Hm strange. Its not on F:\ its on the folder inside F:\home\ When i right click my F drive i don't see that user. Thanks for helping me btw.

Comment: Oke here is what i found now. i found 2 folders containing allot of those numbers. http://i.imgur.com/wjxG5ps.png

Comment: The account with the user id only pops up when i give all users full permissions. Then it shows and i can remove it. But right after taking the drive out and back in. Its just back to the same again.